# Fail to send array of string using ajax C#

Tags: c#, arrays, ajax, post, model-view-controller

I have some trouble to send an array of string using ajax to a C# controller.
I tried many things but i can't make it works.

Here is my C# controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getavailabilities")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetAvailabilities(string[] data)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, new
        {
            data = ""
        });
    }
```

Then my ajax call :

```
function apiExecuteRequest(callback, uri, type, data) {
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: type,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: (apiReply) => {
        callback(apiReply);
    },
    failure: (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        callback({ isSuccess: false, error: textStatus + " " + errorThrown, message: xmlHttpRequest.responseJSON });
    },
    error: (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        callback({ isSuccess: false, error: textStatus + " " + errorThrown, message: xmlHttpRequest.responseJSON });
    }
});
```

}

```
function apiExecuteAuthenticatedRequestAsync(callback, uri, type, data) {
apiGetTokenAsync((token) => {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: (xhr) => {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + token);
        }
    });
    apiExecuteRequest(callback, uri, type, data);
});
```

To get my array i use :

```
var data = this.values2.map(function (item) {return item.ItemId;})
apiExecuteAuthenticatedRequestAsync((response) => {
...
}, apiUrl + 'dashboard/getavailabilities', "POST", data);
```

What i get is everytime Null.
When i set the parameter to object or dynamic i get : {object}.

I really need your help, and thank you for any advice and help you would provide me.

Answer (score 0):

As you know that the dataType of the request is application/json. So you need to convert the data to Json String using JSON.stringify like so:

```
var data = this.values2.map(function (item) {return item.ItemId;})
apiExecuteAuthenticatedRequestAsync((response) => {
...
}, apiUrl + 'dashboard/getavailabilities', "POST", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't fix the problem
The value is : {string[0]}

Comment: What did you get when you console.log(data) before sending it?